# Python vs Java bytecode

Tags: python, pyinstaller, bytecode, platform-independent

I want my python GUI apps to run on all three OSs without need to recompile on each platform. Is python executable created by pyinstaller (by or similar utility) platform independent like Java's bytecode? Java's bytecode runs on Windows, Mac and Linux using JRE.

Comment: Python bytecode runs on a virtual machine, yes. But that's not really relevant to whether or not pyinstaller makes a protable executable

Comment: You don't need to tag this with `[java]`.  You are not actually asking anything about Java, and your Q&A won't help someone asking about Java topics.

Comment: Note that if you bundle a Java application+JVM into an .exe file (or other platforms' equivalents), that will also be platform-specific. You can either have a cross-platform package that requires a VM/interpreter to be installed on the user's system; or you can have a self-contained executable without dependencies that works on a specific platform. You can't have a cross-platform executable with no dependencies (well, there's [this](https://justine.lol/ape.html), but that's still x64-specific and probably not viable for Python or Java).

Answer (score 6):

It's right there in the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html)

> The output of PyInstaller is specific to the active operating system
> and the active version of Python. This means that to prepare a
> distribution for:
>
> - a different OS
> - a different version of Python
> - a 32-bit or 64-bit OS
>
> you run PyInstaller on that OS, under that version of Python. The
> Python interpreter that executes PyInstaller is part of the bundle,
> and it is specific to the OS and the word size.

In other words: no, it's not portable. You need to compile for each platform/architecture.

As stated by @juanpa.arrivillaga in the comments, this has nothing to do with the bytecode python normally executes. That *is* portable. The problem here is that PyInstaller bundles a python interpreter that is os- and architecture- specific (that is, this doesn't work for the same reason you wouldn't normally be able to run a Windows executable on MacOs).

Comment: Important to note, this has nothing to do with *Python bytecode* which *is portable* to any machine that has the right version of the interpreter